# System Extensions Integrations missing from admin. Can't add new Integration

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel, integration

I have a magento 2 site, trying to add a required 'integration' for a 3rd party module. System > Extensions > Integrations is completely missing from the admin menu. Nothing else seems to be missing. I cannot access it directly via url either ("/admin/admin/integration/index/key/xxx"), it just redirects to dashboard.

I have searched high and low and haven't found anything similar being reported by anyone.

There are no relevant errors in magento system, exception or debug logs. No browser console or network errors.

This is the staging site, on the live and local site (same codebase) 'Integrations' *is* there...?

I compared databases and found nothing, but may have missed something.
Magento_Integration module is enabled.

I reset file permissions (like this https://gist.github.com/alihalabyah/e9d5cd077efb4b62cdd40bf4cf75c8ac)

I have cleared caches, redeployed etc.

I turned off the htpasswd just in case this was causing issues.

Anyone else ever seen this issue?? What further steps should I now take to try and fix this?

Would adding integrations manually to 'integrations' and 'oauth_consumer' work? (needs a 'key' and 'secret', not sure if these are meant to be dynamically generated, seems like this way will be trouble..? Would feel better doing it the normal way)

Thanks in advance...! :]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @il0v3d0g Sorry can't remember what happened with this, might have magically re-appeared. Possibly something to do with production / developer modes(?)

Comment: ah I see. Thank you for your response! I actually found out that I was dealing with magento1 which looked totally different and figured that out my problem. thank you tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if is too late for an aswer, but check this link [for enabling some records in core_config_data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325708/missing-import-export-options-under-system-data-transfer-magento-ce-2-4-1)

It worked for me