# Missing Import / Export Options under System->Data Transfer (Magento CE 2.4.1 + Claue Theme)

Tags: import, admin-panel, export, magento2.4

When logged in as an administrative user (with all resources including data transfer allocated), under the System->Data Transfer menu, there are no import /export options available. The entire Data Transfer menu is blank. See below

[image]

I believe this may be caused by the [Claue Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/claue-clean-minimal-magento-2-theme/20155150) that was installed. I am also contacting the vendor to resolve this, but they typically take 3-5 days and am working on a tight timeline.

How can the import/export options be re-enabled? Alternatively, how would one go about trying to troubleshoot the issue?

This is running on:

- Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29, Mysql Ver 14.14-5.7.32, PHP 7.4.12

Am new to the community and Magento, any assistance or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change values of bellow fields from 1 to 0 in core_config_data table

advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Integration
advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_TaxImportExport
advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_ImportExport

Answer (score 0):

To enable import module, please go to your phpmyadmin, find the table named “core_config_data” and search record with path is “advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_ImportExport” and change value of that record to 0: http://prntscr.com/w5a9tr

Enable all ImportExport Module in Phpmyadmin. Thank you